# QT Scaling Gnome

Tags: virtualbox, qt

QT seems to scale twice under gnome.
[image: VirtualBox Scaling -- huge buttons]

When I start QT applications from gnome the icons are huge. When I start `qt5ct` from terminal, the scaling is fixed and icons are normal size.

I have tried:

- Setting the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` environment to 1.
- Setting scaling to 1 in `KDE System Settings`

[Edit]
Setting `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.5` in .\profile seems to scale everything by half, but setting it to any other value reverts back to huge icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0` in `~/.zshrc` seems to have fixed it

Comment: Oh thanks! I search for this every where but all solutions didn't work. It seems this is the deal!

Answer (score 0):

just to mention that the `export` option worked for the same issue on Linux Mint 20. It was triggered by using an external screen with higher resolution than my laptop's.

I have to start Virtual Box from the terminal now, but at least it works properly.
Thanks a lot!